# How can I identify when I can attribute the @@ROWCOUNT (or ROWCOUNT_BIG()) value solely to a single DML operation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**The below is an academic question.**

If I understand correctly, the `@@ROWCOUNT` (and `ROWCOUNT_BIG()`) system variables sum up *all* of the rows affected by a MERGE statement (all INSERTed, UPDATEd, and DELETEd rows, should those operations be specified within the statement), so I'm wondering if it's possible to identify when the number of rows affected by this statement can be attributed solely to a specific operation (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE) within a DML trigger on the object?

If I want to log the number of rows INSERTed into a table, say, is it possible to use @@ROWCOUNT safely through some T-SQL logic without worrying I might be counting UPDATEd and/or DELETEd rows?

I know that I can count the number of rows in the inserted table via an INSERT trigger, but I thought it could be more efficient to use the system variables if I know that only rows were INSERTed, and that none were DELETEd or UPDATEd.

Comment: The practical answer, if you need this, is simply to not use `MERGE`. It can't do anything you can't also do with separate `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements, even if these are more verbose (with the exception of some scenarios involving `OUTPUT`). While it may be possible to sneak in counters through the backdoor by updating variables inside the `MERGE`, there's almost certainly no guarantee that these would give accurate counts, and no real reason to bother (since, again, there are already deterministic, maintainable ways of achieving this).

Comment: Short answer is no - but you already know that. Not certain why you need to know the number of rows but [this old, archived discusson](https://web.archive.org/web/20100102170713/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/steve_kass/archive/2009/04/29/It_2700_s-2008-and-rowcount-ain_2700_t-what-it-used-to-be.-Don_2700_t-use-it-in-triggers_2100_.aspx) discusses the problematic use of merge vs. @@rowcount

Comment: You could `output` the [`$action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) column from the `merge` and then `count` from that. Not as efficient as one might like, but it avoids triggers.